# i need ti get percentage value of every value of array

Tags: mysql

i have a table of result.
in which values are stored like this.

[image: table structure]

i want to get every subjects percentage if students got less than 40% from any subject it will show status failed.

how to do this i have tried percentage but it shows percentage of over all.
i have tried like this

```
"SELECT *,
        avg( sub_marks * 100/sub_total_marks ) AS percentage,
        SUM(sub_marks)  as total,
        SUM(sub_total_marks)  as total_sub,
        GROUP_CONCAT(sub_marks SEPARATOR '</td><tr><tr><td>') sub_marks,
        GROUP_CONCAT(sub_total_marks SEPARATOR '</td><tr><tr><td>') sub_total_marks
FROM result r
JOIN students s
    ON r.std_id = s.student_id
JOIN adm_year a
    ON r.session_id = a.adm_y_id
JOIN class c
    ON r.class_id = c.c_id
JOIN levels l
    ON r.level_id = l.y_id
JOIN section x
    ON r.section_id = x.sec_id
WHERE exam_id = '$exam' AND
      session_id = '$session' AND
      class_id = '$class' AND
      level_id = '$level' AND
      section_id = '$section'
GROUP BY `std_id`"
```

Comment: Please show some sample output as well.  At first glance I don't know exactly what you want here.

Comment: i want to get percentage of every subject. like subj 1 obt marks 22 from 50 i want to get subject wise percentage

Comment: Show us the exact output you expect based on the sample data you gave us above.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen check i attached pic

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen kindly check

Answer (score 0):

i want display like this. want to get percentage of every subject

[image: i want like this]